# PHP Group Use Declarations not working as expected

Tags: php, class

I currently use

```
<?php
namespace App;

use App\ItemTypes\AbstractItem;
use App\ItemTypes\AgedBrie;
use App\ItemTypes\Backstage;
use App\ItemTypes\Conjured;
use App\ItemTypes\Normal;
use App\ItemTypes\Sulfuras;
```

However I wanted to try the feature in PHP 7+ where I can group them so tried

```
use App\ItemTypes\{AbstractItem,AgedBrie,Backstage,Conjured,Normal,Sulfuras};
```

However I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Normal' not found
```

Normal

```
<?php

namespace App\ItemTypes;

class Normal extends AbstractItem
```

Comment: Have added what it is set in Normal - looks ok to me

Comment: does the file name is Normal or Normal.php? also, why is your OS? windows or Linux?

Comment: Normal.php on Ubuntu

Comment: are you sure that you'd loaded the autoloader correctly? in linux the file system is case-sensitive

Comment: Yes - it works with the "original" way of including them but doesn't when I group them so I am sure it works fine using it the old way

Comment: Are yu sure that it the code triggering the problem? A `use`  statement does not yet trigger the autoloader, but the usage of the imported class does. How do you use `Normal`  later on in your code?

Comment: Have done a quick repo: https://github.com/MyBoyPop/test @NicoHaase

Comment: How do you use the given code? As far as I see, you don't have any autoloader in these files. Also, please add all relevant information to your question by editing it. Don't put your source code anywhere else than in your question